# Click event on dynamic button in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a datatables element on my page with a hidden first column, and an empty column at the end to contain a button.

I'm trying to get the click event of that button to:

1. Hide the button,
2. Show a 'loading' icon - fontawesome icon already in the column
3. Retrieve the value of the hidden columns corresponding row
4. Show a success/fail icon - to be added but will be a fontawesome icon

CSHTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="SignOffTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>DATA_ID</th>
                    <th>KPI Name</th>
                    <th>Value 1</th>
                    <th>Value 2</th>
                    <th>Value 3</th>
                    <th>Date For</th>
                    <th>Value Type</th>
                    <th>Added By</th>
                    <th>Added On</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
            {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @item.DATAID
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.KPIHead
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.Value1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.Value2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.Value3
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.FromDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.Type
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.AddedBy
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.AddedOn.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                        </td>
                        <td id="ActionCol">
                            <button id="TableSignOff" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" data-interaction="@item.DATAID">Sign Off</button>
                            <div id="Loader"><span id="Loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-fw"></span></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div#Loader").hide();

        var table = $('#SignOffTable').DataTable({
            paging: true,
            searching: false,
            ordering: false,
            pagingType: "simple_numbers",
            lengthChange: false,
            bfilter: true,
            info: true,
            "columnDefs": [
            { "visible": false, "targets": 0 }
            ]
        });
    });

    $("#SignOffTable button").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('div#Loader').show();
        var trElem = $(this).closest("tr");
        var firstTd = $(trElem).children("td")[0];
        alert($(firstTd).text())
    })
</script>
```

However I can't seem to access the hidden column's data, or successfully hide the button/show the loading spinner. The spinner icon is hidden upon page load, and the button click will hide that button but will then show all the spinners in the column, rather than just that specific one.

Comment: you're creating multiple elements with the same ID everywhere (because of your @foreach). This is invalid HTML - IDs must be unique. Your code can't understand which element you mean, so it doesn't work properly. Give the elements unique IDs (or no IDs at all) and uses classes and scope to identify the ones you want to manipulate.

Comment: You suggest to create the table another way? Only, it's being built from a model querying a database result set so will be different each time. There is a unique identifier in the hidden column - is it possible to use that as a unique identifier?

Comment: not directly, to identify the elements. You don't need to create the table a different way, you just need to change the output slightly so you don't create duplicate IDs.

Comment: OK - any suggestions on how/where to look to get started with that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating duplicate IDs for your elements. This is invalid HTML and will cause your code to be confused about which elements it's trying to access.

Something more like this should help, using classes rather than IDs:

```
<td>
  <button class="TableSignOff btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" data-interaction="@item.DATAID">Sign Off</button>
  <div class="Loader" hidden>
    <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-fw" ></span>
  </div>
</td>
```

And

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var table = $('#SignOffTable').DataTable({
        paging: true,
        searching: false,
        ordering: false,
        pagingType: "simple_numbers",
        lengthChange: false,
        bfilter: true,
        info: true,
        "columnDefs": [
        { "visible": false, "targets": 0 }
        ]
    });
});

$("#SignOffTable .TableSignOff").click(function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.hide(); //hide the button
    btn.parent().find(".Loader").show(); //show the loader within the button's parent td
    alert(btn.data("interaction")); //output the DATAID
})
```

Also note that the loaders are hidden at the start by markup rather than code, so you don't get any momentary showing of the loaders before the code runs.

Comment: So close..!! Your code alerts the hidden column and hides that specific button but the loading spinner doesn't show...

Comment: @danverbs _technically_ it doesn't alert the hidden column contents at all. It alerts the value placed into the "data-interaction" property of the button. This just happens to be the same value as in the hidden column, presumably because you coded it that way. It might sound picky, and it's just a technical thing but I find when documenting and debugging code it helps to be as precise as possible about what is actually happening. e.g. You could change the content of the hidden column without altering this code at all, and then your statement would be untrue. Something to think about that's all

Comment: @danverbs in relation to the loading spinner, I put the "hidden" command on the wrong element - it should be on the element with the "Loading" class. Have updated the answer and it should now work correctly.

Comment: no you are right I did see that in the code and I put totally the wrong thing! I can see it's picking up the value from the button as opposed to this hidden column - always good to be technically correct with things like this! However, the loader is still not showing with the updated class...

Comment: @danverbs it should be. See simplified example here: https://jsfiddle.net/jz83jx0o/ - I haven't got whatever graphics are defined by the classes you've added to the span, so I've just put the text "Loading" in there instead, so you can see it. Maybe that's your problem - missing graphics?

Comment: yes I thought this too as it's doing everything but. I made the Loader div visible by default and the icon shows on page load. Just changed it to show the text "Loading" like in the example but that doesn't display either. No errors showing in the console, could this be a bug/thing with DataTables?

Comment: possibly could be. Can you make a fiddle which demonstrates the problem? You'd only need one row of example data. Just fork mine and add the datatables stuff. P.S. You did remove the "hidden" from the span as well, didn't you? :-)

Comment: Yes definitely removed "hidden" from the span! Well I put it all into a fiddle and it worked so I'm at a loss here now.

Comment: There must be some difference between your fiddle and your application then. You just have to find it. That's kind of down to you because I can't see either of them. So...if this has helped you, would you consider upvoting / marking as answered? I think it solves the problem as described, your only issue now is effectively a deployment problem - the concept as I described does work

Comment: Yep sure was going to anyway. Thanks for all your help - I'll continue investigating my app this end.

Comment: Got it working now. I created a blank page and just tried it on there and still wouldn't work. Might be some bootstrap v4 issue around showing divs that have been hidden. Had to hide it in (document).ready then it will show on button click. Strange. Thanks again